Is it possible to use fragments optionally in thyemleaf?
In SpringBoot3, I made a code with fragments like this.
<body>

    <div th:replace="~{fragments/header::header}"></div>

I would like to use it optionally. For example, in the view of Main, the header fragment will be shown, however, it would be disappeared in the view of List.
In fact, I asked GPT-4, and it gave me solutions, but they don't work.
<div th:replace="~{fragments/header::header}" th:if="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI.endsWith('/main')}"></div>

<div th:replace="~{fragments/header::header}" th:if="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI.replace(#httpServletRequest.contextPath, '') == '/main'}"></div>


What happens when you write more than one th:* attribute in the same tag? This is defined as Attribute Precedence. There is no need to guess, just look at the order.

Should be possible by wrapping the fragment in a th:block with the if condition I think.
Pretty sure the example doesn't work because th:replace replaces the div element before computing the if condition that was on it.
<th:block th:if="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI.endsWith('/main')}">
  <div th:replace="~{fragments/header::header}" />
</th:block>


It doesn't work, but I found the other way.
